# Reference request: Weak harnack inequality for biharmonic equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I have seen a lemma which I do not have any reference or hint for it.

> Assume $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^N} $ is smooth bounded domain and 
>   let $u$ be a positive distributional supersolution to 
>   \begin{cases} \Delta^2 u = 0 \hspace{.9cm} \mathrm{in} \hspace{.1cm} Ω \\
>  u =-\Delta u= 0 \hspace{.9cm} \mathrm{on} \hspace{.1cm} ∂Ω \end{cases}
>   then for any $B_R(x_0) ⊂⊂ Ω $, there exists a positive constant $C = C(θ, ρ, q,R)$ , $0 <q< \dfrac{N}{ N−2}$ , $0 <θ<ρ< 1$ , such that
>
> $$||u||_{L^q(B_{ρR}(x_0))}  \leq C  \hspace{.2cm} ess \inf_{B_{θR}(x_0)}u$$

I need a reference or hint, or any help to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: The normal approach for Navier BC would be to take $v:= - \Delta u$ and see what $v$ satisfies.  (Note in this case I think the only solution is $u=0$)...

Comment: Thanks, I found the version of laplacian operator case in Lecture notes of courant institute ( QING HAN and FANGHUA LIN ). and with this change of variable, I achieve the result. For solutions, $u=0$ is the only one. but in the question I mean supersolution.

Comment: oh sorry...didn't see "supersolution"